# Creating multipart/mixed request

Tags: karate

I have a very specific case I'm trying to test with Karate.

```
PUT https://test-api.com/endpoint
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY
--BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json

{"type": "json-api-object"}
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="fieldname"; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Encoding: base64

<binary data>
--BOUNDARY--
```

Examples show multipart/mixed requests, but they don't show how to set the content-type header on each part. I tried using `And multipart header...` but that didn't parse correctly.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature

If I can get this figured out with your help, I'll make a PR against the examples to hopefully help someone in the future.

Comment: I am facing similar issue but much complex payload. Were you about to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is the first time I'm seeing a need for a custom content-type for *each* part. This will need a change in the code, so yes [an example will expedite a fix](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue).

Meanwhile you can [customize the content-type](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/content-type.feature) for normal requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using `mulipart files`

```
  * configure headers = {"Content-Type": 'multipart/mixed'}
  * configure charset = null
  * def mFiles = {}
  * set mFiles.jsondata = { value: {'type': 'json-api-object'}, contentType: 'application/vnd.api+json' }
  * set mFiles.fieldname = { read: 'classpath:path/to/somePhoto.jpg', filename: 'filename.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
  Given url "https://my-api.com/put"
  And multipart files mFiles
  When method PUT
```

According to [this comment](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1710#issuecomment-895369103), `multipart file` is preferred for anything other than a string in a multipart field.